Issue iterating over collections in MongoDB from mongo shell
I am trying to create a script that connects to a MongoDB instance, selects a database, lists all the collections from a database and then creates a schema to use for validation from a sample of documents. The latter half of this I have figured out, but I am completely stumped as to how to do the first part. Here's what I have so far this is file runner.js that I am loading from mongosh by running load("runner.js") in the shell prompt:
async function run() {
    const db = connect('mongodb://localhost/mainDB')

    // const collections = db.runCommand({
    //     listCollections: 1.0,
    //     nameOnly: true
    // });
    const coll = db.listCollections();

    console.log(collections);

    for await (const doc of collections) {
        console.log(doc);
    }
}

run().catch(reason => console.error('ERROR RUNNING: ', reason));

When I run the above, I get the following error:
ERROR RUNNING:  TypeError: db.listCollections is not a function
Bollocks, the API documentation says it's a method https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.9/classes/Db.html#listCollections
No matter, though, when I uncomment out the commented section above and use the runCommand method, I get the following error:
{
  cursor: {
    id: Long('0'),
    ns: 'mainDB.$cmd.listCollections',
    firstBatch: [
      { name: 'purchaseOrderLineItems', type: 'collection' },
      { name: 'transactionCost', type: 'collection' },
      { name: 'addresses', type: 'collection' },
      ...<more I am not listing here>
    ]
  },
  ok: 1
}
ERROR RUNNING:  TypeError: collections is not async iterable


This also doesn't make sense. Documentation here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/ says that the cursor, (which this is, right) implements the async iterable interface, so this should work.
Would someone clarify what is going on here?

The error makes sense because the result is not a iterable items, so loop based on the response you get in console. You can't use db.listCollections() inside mongo-shell, use either db.runCommand or db.getCollectionInfos method. Refer this

Can you post  the code for connect from: const db = connect('mongodb://localhost/mainDB')

Well in the code I'm just connecting to a local instance and the db I'm using is called mainDB, so that's it. I've rewritten the script and made some progress and am trying to use a connection string to connect to remote instances, but I obviously won't post that here as it would compromise the security of the system.
